# Just another state

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I was bored, so I came out with a really simple riddle.

> You see me whenever there is a thunderstorm, 
>   yet at the same time I may appear in your home. 
>   I can be far away among the stars, 
>   finding me in your blood is not one bit bizarre.  
>   What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> Plasma

You see me whenever there is a thunderstorm,

> Plasma plays a role in thunderstorms.

yet at the same time I may appear in your home.

> It is found in lamps.

I can be far away among the stars,

> Stars are largely composed of plasma.

finding me in your blood is not one bit bizarre.

> Blood contains blood plasma.

Also, the title,

Just another state

> Plasma is a state of matter.

Comment: That was fast! As expected of Puzzling community :)